# Pegar valores de array retornado de outra classe

Tags: java, array

Preciso passar o valor da variável `sgEstado` para a outra classe mas não consigo, o valor esta no `return` quando *debugo*, mas não consigo fazer o valor sair na outra classe.

```
 ArrayList estados;
            try {
                Session session = InitSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
                estados = (ArrayList) session.createCriteria(FilialComplementoTO.class).addOrder(Order.asc("sgEstado")).list();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).error(e.getMessage());
                throw new IntegrationException(e);
            }
            return estados;
        }
```

Segundo código, se o valor do sgEstado sair no "passou" abaixo está ótimo, Grato.

```
try {
            ctx.get(FilialComplementoTO.FILIAL_COMPLEMENTO_KEY);
            //FilialComplementoTO filialComplementoTO = (FilialComplementoTO) ctx.get(FilialComplementoTO.FILIAL_COMPLEMENTO_KEY);
            LocalizarLojasCompositeEntity localizarLojasCompositeEntity = new LocalizarLojasCompositeEntity();
            localizarLojasCompositeEntity.findEstadosBySgEstado();
            System.out.println(localizarLojasCompositeEntity.findEstadosBySgEstado());
            System.out.println("passou");
}
```

Comment: O código de cima é o método `localizarLojasCompositeEntity.findEstadosBySgEstado()`? O que acontece quando você executa? Aparece algo que não deveria? Se você garante que `estados` tem um valor o único problema é que você está retornando um `ArrayList`, ou seja uma variável com vários elementos. Você não pode mandar imprimir um `ArrayList` como um todo, você precisaria imprimir os elementos dele (mesmo assim depende de como é cada elemento deste *array*). Isto normalmente é feito com `for in`.

Comment: O código é o localizarLojasCompositeEntity, ele executa normalmente quando executado, aparece o "passou" e verifico que o valor de 'estados' que é uma lista fica correto, com os dados que desejo, no outro código eu não sei como puxar da lista criada acima apenas o campo "SgEstado", que é o campo que desejo para fazer uma filtragem pelo estado do cliente. Não sei como puxar apenas um dado da lista construída no método findEstadosBySgEstado()

Comment: E qual é o conteúdo (tipo) de cada elemento deste `ArrayList`?

Comment: A resposta ajudou? Você pode aceitá-la.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que o que você precisa fazer é só varrer o *array* retornado pelo método que fornece a lista de estados:

```
try {
    ctx.get(FilialComplementoTO.FILIAL_COMPLEMENTO_KEY);
    //FilialComplementoTO filialComplementoTO = (FilialComplementoTO) ctx.get(FilialComplementoTO.FILIAL_COMPLEMENTO_KEY);
    LocalizarLojasCompositeEntity localizarLojasCompositeEntity = new LocalizarLojasCompositeEntity();
    estados = localizarLojasCompositeEntity.findEstadosBySgEstado();
    for(string estado : estados) {
        System.out.println(estado);
    }
    System.out.println("passou");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Traverse.java)

Chutei que no `ArrayList` de `estados` existem *strings*. Se não for isto precisaria trocar o tipo no `for in` e se o tipo for outra estrutura de dados, pegar o elemento específico que deseja imprimir.